# Which is more important for Google Adsense, traffic or context?

Tags: google-adsense, blog

I have a great amount of experience as an online blogger, but till now i only did my blogging as a hobby and did not use Adsense on my blog(s).

Now that I've decided to use Adsense I'm facing a big question. I can write contents in

1. An area which has low CPC (close to 0.00$) but has some decent search volume per month (something like 500k per month) or
2. An area which has higher CPC (something like a dollar) but there is fewer visits per month (10kish per month).

Does CPC matter enough that I should write in #2? or are Google ads personalized enough that I can choose #1?

Answer (score 1):

I have been earning via Adsense for about 2 years now, and I have learned a lot. The two scenarios you gave does not ensure if you will do well. Google's algorithm is now paying Adsense user by the geographical regions of the audience. No matter if I write high CPC keywords or Low CPC keywords, if my audience is from US, UK or Europe then I will earn better, even with just 100,000 visitors a month, comparing to the person who has 500,000 visitors a month from a Third world country such as Pakistan, Bangladesh etc.

You should focus more on your content quality, rather than just CPC. Because Google will rank your content better if it is SEO optimized and with better keywords. Because that is what will give your visitors from your desired country.

Furthermore, Google only needs 2,000 Unique views a month on your blog to get your application approved. But that is not the only criteria, you must have quality blogs as well as few backlinks to your website before you apply for it.